# Upgrading from Struts 2.5 to Struts 6 issue

Tags: struts2, struts, struts2-jquery

This Ajax call is not working when upgraded to Struts 6.3.0.2. I have included JQuery plugin in pom.xml. I think the problem is sj:div. Any help on this is so much appreciated

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

<s:url action="test_actionMethod" var="desUrl" />
        <s:form id="getActionForm" cssStyle="display:none;">
</s:form>

<sj:div cssStyle="text-align:center" id="test" href="%{desUrl}" formIds="getActionForm" loadingText="Loading..." indicator="indicator" listenTopics="/refresh" escapeHtmlBody="true">
</sj:div>
```

Comment: _"not working "_ - explain in detail

Comment: It should trigger test_actionmethod while loading the page and display the results but it is displaying blank page

Comment: It says JQuery not defined and $ is not defined in the browser console even though I added struts Jquery plugin

Comment: The jquery is not loaded. Update the latest version struts  jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom filter which is blocking jquery.struts2.min.js?s2j=5.0.3